# Using debi from devscripts?

Tags: debian, deb

I'm slightly confused on what exactly `debi` does.

I was building OLA, and I found this post: [Error when building .debs for BBB with newest OLA 0.9.7... – Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/open-lighting/debuild%7Csort:date/open-lighting/7s2qItlNQFA/37rCCuCwCQAJ) where I had seen:

```
cd ola-0.9.7  
debuild  
# (... wait ...)  
sudo debi
```

So, I did build with `debuild`, and I got these .debs as a result:

```
$ ls -1 ../*.deb
../libola1_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
../libola1-dbgsym_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
../libola-dev_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
../ola_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
../ola-dbgsym_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
../ola-python_0.10.7-1_all.deb
../ola-rdm-tests_0.10.7-1_all.deb
```

The thing is, when I first installed OLA through the binary packages (Raspbian), before this build, I ended up with the packages `ola libola1 ola-rdm-tests ola-python` installed (which I had uninstalled before the build).

So, I'm not sure, if I just run `debi`, will I get just those packages installed, or will it install *all* the .debs that were generated (including `-dbgsym` and `-dev` packages, which in this particular case, I don't need)?

In other words, if I just want some of those .deb packages installed, am I better off just doing `sudo dpkg -i [package1] [package2] ...`, instead of using `sudo debi`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`debi`](https://manpages.debian.org/debi) installs all the packages listed in the `.changes` file produced during the build, so yes, it ends up installing all the packages produced by the build, including development packages and debug symbols.

If you want to limit the set of packages which are installed, without having to figure out their version or architecture, you can use `debi` with a list of package names, and it will figure out which packages to install by combining that with the `.changes` file:

```
sudo debi ola libola1 ola-rdm-tests ola-python
```

Comment: But, also from the manpage: "If a list of packages is given on the command line, then only those  debs  with  names  in this list of packages will be installed."

Comment: Indeed @muru, I was just testing that ;-). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a ton - that last command worked great!